# Xammp. send mail through localhost dont work

Tags: php

i use xammp and i want to configure XAMPP to send mail from my localhost
through gmail.

i did the right settings to do that but somehow my localhost dont send an e-mail.

here are my settings in the php.ini file and sendmail.ini file.

php.ini:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port= 587
sendmail_from = example@gmail.com
sendmail_path = sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

sendmail.ini:


[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username= example@gmail.com
auth_password= *********
force_sender=example@gmail.com
```

What do i wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors and/or Have you checked all pertinent error logs?

Comment: I dont get any errors.

Comment: And about the second question. What are the contents of those 2 files there, `error.log` and `debug.log`?